# How to refresh grid panel's store within a floating form panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, gridpanel

I am working on this `ExtJS 4` app, where I have a part to Manage app users.

The form pops up like a window `floating: true`.

```
var user_grid_form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',
{
    xtype       : 'form-grid',
    frame       : true,
    title       : 'User Information',
    floating    : true,
    draggable   : true,
    closable    : true,
    closeAction : 'hide',
    bodyPadding : 5,
    layout      : 'column',
    closeAction : 'destroy',
    width       : 532,
    items       : 
    [
        user_grid,
        user_textfield
    ],
    buttons :
    [
       {
            text    : 'Save Edits',
            icon    : 'images/save.png',
            handler : handleUpdates
       },
       {
            text    : 'Delete User',
            icon    : 'images/delete.png',
            handler : handleDeletes
       }
    ]
}).show();
```

The `user_grid` is the grid in my window panel that shows `usernames`

Now, the issue is that when I select a username, just like `jhony` and press `Delete User` my `handleDeletes` updates the database via `Ajax`. But then I try to refresh the `user_grid` and it will not work. **After the deletion, the user should disappear from `user_grid`**

This is what I have tried to do inside the `handleDeletes`:

```
user_store.splice(ind, 1);      // I removed `jhony` from `user_store` 
                                // which is the `store` for `user_grid`             
user_grid.getView().refresh();  // Now trying to refresh and NO ERRORS NO ACTIONS
```

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you want to do is:

```
user_grid.getStore().remove(yourRecord); //remove record from the store and also from the grid view
user_grid.getStore().sync(); //send changes to the server
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
user_grid.getView().refresh();
```

try

```
user_grid.store.load();
```

and no need to do anything else(splice) on the store if deletion is performed server side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer **`dbrin`** but it did not work.

I figured that there is no need to touch `user_grid` grid panel. I just needed to update it's `store`.
The store had `data` and once I did this, everything worked:

```
user_store.splice(ind, 1);  
u_store.load(user_store);
// u_store is the store that has user_store data
```